# Qt error cannot find -lQtCore -lQtGui -lQtTest -QtOpenGl -lcore on linux ubuntu 16.04

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, qt-creator

I am using Qt 5.12.2 on a linux ubuntu 16.04 and when I execute a program I get an error saying that it is not finding -lQtCore, -lQtGui, -lQtTest, -lQtOpenGl and -lcore and I also get

> collect2 error: ld returned 1 exit status.

What can i do to fix this?

I have already tried solving this using the command `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev` and `sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev`

Comment: Mesa has nothing with Qt, install development files for Qt libraries.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you do not have the Qt5 libraries installed on your system.  The libraries are included with the Qt Creator runtime, so it can always find them.  When you run an executable outside of Qt Creator, you must (typically) copy the libraries required to the folder where the executable has been placed.

Check out the details in the docs.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-deployment.html